# Bind angular datepicker and timepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I want to bind angular timepicker and datepicker. I am using [Angular bootstrap library](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

As per documentation of timepicker, it requires `new Date` object for min and max values.
If I simply set like this

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours( 2 );
d.setMinutes( 0 );
$scope.minTime = d;

var d = new Date();
d.setHours( 11 );
d.setMinutes( 0 );
$scope.maxTime = d;

<uib-timepicker ng-model="mytime" min="min" max="max" show-meridian="false" min="minTime" max="maxTime"></uib-timepicker>
```

This works only for **today** because of `new Date()` object.

I want it to work on any day I select. Currently, timepicker is not restricting time as required. Also, sometimes timepicker box borders turn red (It may be due to validation errors), but does not specify what exactly is the error.

**Please have a look at:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/LOZ9T6zexRkQpqSIaJiA?p=preview

Comment: try this  : $scope.today = function() {
     $scope.dt = new Date( "21/10/2014");
   };

Comment: I want to set it dynamically, whichever date i select from date picker , min max time of timepicker should be set 2 to 4...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to initialize `timepicker` according to the *selected date* replace `dateChange` function with:

```
$scope.dateChange = function() {
    var selectedDate = $scope.dt;
    var min = new Date(selectedDate.getTime());
    min.setHours(2);
    min.setMinutes(0);
    $scope.min = min;

    var max = new Date(selectedDate.getTime());
    max.setHours(4);
    max.setMinutes(0);
    $scope.max = max;
}
```

**Working example**

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.format = 'yyyy/MM/dd';
    $scope.min = null;
    $scope.max = null;


     $scope.initTimePicker = function(selectedDate) {
        var min = new Date(selectedDate.getTime());
        min.setHours(2);
        min.setMinutes(0);
        $scope.min = min;

        var max = new Date(selectedDate.getTime());
        max.setHours(4);
        max.setMinutes(0);
        $scope.max = max;
    }

    
    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.dt = new Date();
        $scope.initTimePicker($scope.dt);
    };
    $scope.init();

    $scope.clear = function() {
        $scope.dt = null;
    };

    $scope.open = function() {
        $scope.popup.opened = true;
    };

   
    $scope.popup = {
        opened: false
    };

   
  
    $scope.dateChange = function() { 
        $scope.initTimePicker($scope.dt);
    }
    

});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.4.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  
<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
     
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                    ng-required="true" close-text="Close" ng-change="dateChange()" />

                    <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <uib-timepicker ng-model="dt" hour-step="1" minute-step="15" name="sTime"   show-meridian="true" min="min" max="max">
        </uib-timepicker>

        <pre class="alert alert-info">Time is: {{dt | date:'M/d/yyyy HH:mm' }}</pre>


 </div>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eJCkYOHs8s1YkRwqbdPL?p=preview)

Comment: Have a look when date is changed. Boxes on timepicker turn red(Maybe due to validation). Also, Min max is not working for default date now.

Comment: The example has been updated to initialize time picker for default date.  Since we are specifying min and max properties Timepicker  buttons turn red once current time is set to out of time interval

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Works fine.I had 1 change however, $scope.dt = new Date() then $scope.dt.setHours(2);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428210/how-to-set-time-pop-up-in-the-angular-ui-bootstrap-datepicker-pop-up could plz see this link